# What is an elegant way to perform a set of statements for all pytest tests?

Tags: python, decorator, pytest

I am writing my first py.test tests and I have written the tests something like below

```
class Test_X_Values(object):
   def test_value_1(self, fix_A):
       A = fix_A['first']
       B = fix_A['second']
       # some statements here
       #the following part is common for all
       if ( A.X == True and B.Y == True):
           #perform something. for example
           print 'performing'

   def test_value_2(self, fix_A):
       #some statements
       if ( A.X == True and B.Y == True):
           #perform something. for example
           print 'performing'
```

So I decided to write a function

```
def check(self, A, B):
   if ( A.X == True and B.Y == True):
      #perform something. for example
      print 'performing'
```

Is there any elegant way to perform this function 'check' at the end of every tests other than writing check(A,B) at the end of every tests?

Comment: what is wrong with "writing check(A,B) at the end of every tests"  ?

Comment: you could technically hide the calling of `check` with a metaclass or decorators but in either of those cases you would have to `return A,B` in order to pass those values to some wrapper that then calls `check(A,B)` so you are not actually saving yourself any work. (and it certainly would not be elegant)

Comment: you could use teardown method to check your statement. as teardown method will be called for each test, this will work better if all the tests are doing the same thing.    ` def teardown_method(self,method) : `